# Unable to run a function with a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, select

I want to build a sql function that returns array of rows based on a select statement, unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

```
create or replace function latestOilFee()
return array
IS
Begin
select * from oil_tracker order by ts desc fetch first 1 row only;
End;
```

console throws an error

```
syntax error at or near "return"
```

Comment: What return an array? Why not return a table (set of rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes

1. RETURNS instead of RETURN
2. For ARRAY you have to mentioned like text[]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION latestOilFee()
  RETURNS text[] AS $$
  select array[fieldname::text, fieldname::text]
  FROM oil_tracker limit 1
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Please check above, you should mentioned fields type while creating array

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be RETURNS (not RETURN)?